# Angular 5: Dynamic load of service and components

Tags: angular, dynamic, service, components, loading

I'm trying to build a dynamic application in Angular 5, which means dynamic loading of services and components. Example:

`myApp 
  |......................
  |         |           |
  |    componentA  componentB
  |         |           | 
  ....................... 
            | 
         serviceA`

So, all the service and the components will be loaded dynamically, in process of running the application. And the service will be used by the app and the components as well.

At the moment, i'm able to load component dynamically by using `componentFactoryResolver`. But, how to load the service and to provide it for the app and the copmponents (as one instance preferably)?